# Тыс vs k vs к при сокращении

Tags: обсуждение, локализация

Если это **кило**, то должна быть **к**, а не **k**.

Если это **kilo**, то почему мы не переводим тогда как **тыс**?

Японцы, к примеру, локализуют:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `.reputation-score { text-transform: uppercase; }`

Comment: @Qwertiy вы живы! Рад видеть)

Comment: @Qwertiy вот еще [прикол с озаглавливанием буков](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314774/339911). P.S. Подправьте, плиз, коммент про дубликат выше.